# PHP & MySQL database storing the name Array problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP & MySQL and I keep getting the word Array stored in my MySQL tables fields `$skill`, `$experience`, `$years`I was wondering how can I fix this problem?

And I know I need to add `mysqli_real_escape_string` which I left out to make code more easier to read Hopefully.

Here is the PHP & MySQL code.

```
if (isset($_POST['info_submitted'])) {

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT learned_skills.*, users_skills.* 
                                   FROM learned_skills 
                                   INNER JOIN users_skills ON learned_skills.id = users_skills.skill_id 
                                   WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
    return;
}

$user_id = '5';
$skill = $_POST['skill'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$years = $_POST['years'];

if (isset($_POST['skill'][0]) && trim($_POST['skill'][0])!=='') {

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT learned_skills.*, users_skills.* FROM learned_skills INNER JOIN users_skills ON users_skills.skill_id = learned_skills.id WHERE users_skills.user_id='$user_id'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0) {

for ($s = 0; $s < count($skill); $s++){
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($experience); $x++){
        for ($g = 0; $g < count($years); $g++){

                    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
                    $query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO learned_skills (skill, experience, years) 
                                                    VALUES ('" . $s . "', '" . $x . "', '" . $g . "')");

                    $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

                    if ($query1 == TRUE) {
                            $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
                            $query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO users_skills (skill_id, user_id) 
                                                            VALUES ('$id', '$user_id')");

                    }   
        }
    }
}
}
}
}
```

Here is the XHTML code.

```
<li><label for="skill">Skill: </label><input type="text" name="skill[0]" id="skill[0]" />
<label for="experience">Experience: </label>
<?php

echo '<select id="experience[0]" name="experience[0]">' . "\n";
  foreach($experience_options as $option) {
    if ($option == $experience) {
      echo '<option value="' . $option . '" selected="selected">' . $option . '</option>' . "\n";
    } else {
      echo '<option value="'. $option . '">' . $option . '</option>'."\n";
    }
  }
echo '</select>';

?>
<label for="years">Years: </label>
<?php

echo '<select id="years[0]" name="years[0]">' . "\n";
  foreach($grade_options as $option) {
    if ($option == $years) {
      echo '<option value="' . $option . '" selected="selected">' . $option . '</option>' . "\n";
    } else {
      echo '<option value="'. $option . '">' . $option . '</option>'."\n";
    }
  }
echo '</select>';

?>
</li>
```

Comment: actually your code is terrible to read, due to poor formatting, repetitive code and obscure logic. so, better you keep escaping but make it more readable.

Comment: How is my code terrible to read and how would you format. obscure logic i think not.

Comment: I did format it, in one of your previous questions. You just pay no attention and repeat same errors again and again. But of course you blame other people for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your error point in clear, I thought you may get coding wrong in this place please check this

```
  for ($s = 0; $s < count($skill); $s++){
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($experience); $x++){
        for ($g = 0; $g < count($years); $g++){

                    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
                    $query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO learned_skills (skill, experience, years) 
                                                    VALUES ('" . $skill[$s] . "', '" . $experience[$x] . "', '" . $years[$g] . "')");

                    $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

                    if ($query1 == TRUE) {
                            $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
                            $query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO users_skills (skill_id, user_id) 
                                                            VALUES ('$id', '$user_id')");

                    }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted the code but I still get the error. Thanks for the try.